Why does ASP.NET Core Web API not allow me to use custom user identity?
I simply want to use a custom user identity class.
The issue?
When I try everything stops working. Swagger returns 404 not found for anything with the [Authorize] attribute and only sees those without it. Even if I log in and send a token the server says the user is not logged in even though they have valid token.
According to everything I find this should be a simple task. Tutorials say I should be able to implement IdentityUser and register it in program.cs with
builder.Services.AddIdentity<TestUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)

But it doesn't work.
Here's an example:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection");

builder.Services.AddSignalR();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.Configure<WebConfig>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Audience = "Test";
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:1111/";
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ClockSkew = TokenValidationParameters.DefaultClockSkew,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidAudience = "Test",
        ValidIssuer = "https://localhost:1111/",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is my custom Secret key for authentication@123"))
    };
});

builder.Services.AddIdentity<TestUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
{
    option.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = " API", Version = "v1" });
    option.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter a valid token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id="Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[]{}
        }
    });
});
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = ".Test.Session";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors(x => x.AllowCredentials().AllowAnyHeader().WithOrigins("http://localhost:2222"));

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSession();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

If I run that it complains it can't find the DI it needs for user store and role store, even if I tell it to use my own stores. If I add
builder.Services.AddTransient< IUserStore<TestUser>, UserStore>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>, RoleStore>();

It will find them and build. But then it goes to never actually calling any of their methods and just returns 404 not found. With break points I can see not one of the methods UserStore or RoleStore are hit.
Role store :
public class RoleStore : IRoleStore<IdentityRole>
public class RoleStore : IRoleStore<IdentityRole>{}

User store:
public class UserStore : IUserStore<TestUser>{}

Neither have any custom code yet so there's nothing to show. Every implemented method in them just has throw new NotImplementedException(); and a break point on every method to see if its called or not.
If I get rid of my custom code it works again, aka remove the
builder.Services.AddIdentity<TestUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true);

it uses the built in way and works. No 404 and user is authenticated.
Right now all I want is for the server to accept the token sent and authenticate the user. No db calls or anything special. Without custom code it works fine and says the user is authenticated. With custom code it returns 404.
What am I missing to make the Web API work with my IdentityUser class?
I've tried moving around the call order, custom IRoleStore and IUserStore, even made/used a IdentityDbContext<TestUser>. None of it helped. I tried calling the AddUserStore and AddRoleStore to ensure it knew to use my classes. Didn't work.

Sounds like you are testing something, so could you share your test repo which can reproduce the issue for us? It may save your a lot of time, and please hide your sensitive information.
